# Regex - Replace text between tags with new line characters

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have extracted the request text from a soaupui request and I'm trying to replace everything from  with a new header. I have tried several different expressions but having trouble matching I think because the text contains new line characters.

Below is the latest one I have tried

```
strRequest3 = strRequest3.replaceAll("<soapenv:Envelope(.*?
\\R)<soapenv:Header/>","<soap:Envelope " + strNewHeader + "</soap:Header>");
log.info strRequest3
```

Sample XML below where I'm trying to insert a new first line and header

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:urn="urn:dhs-gov-au:ccs:pms:sessionreport">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
```

Any ideas on what regex I can try to achieve the above would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Don't process XML (or HTML for that matter) using regular expressions. Just... don't.

Comment: I tried using XMLParser and XMLSlurper in the first instance but didn't get very far. I could extract the text out of the tags but I need the whole lot, tags, values, namespaces, etc so it seemed easier to do it this way. Open to suggestions for improvements

Comment: @user3803807, what is input and expected xml? By the way, is it any related to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091167/extract-soap-header-out-of-request-and-add-it-to-following-request) which was solved already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719261/is-there-an-easier-way-to-parse-xml-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you want `.*` to match newlines you will have to use `s` flag (dotall) for regex.

In Java you can set this flag by adding `(?s)` in front of regex.

```
String str = "<soapenv:Envelope>123123\n" +
            "123123\n" +
            "1231422343\n<soapenv:Header/>";
String replacement = "new";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?s)<soapenv:Envelope>(.*)<soapenv:Header/>",
            "<soapenv:Envelope>" + replacement + "<soapenv:Header/>"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and now get an error "named capturing group has 0 length name. Is there something else I need to include to specify the group?